# I really need to downvote an answer I upvoted a while ago, and thus is now vote-locked!

Tags: discussion

The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994661/3486684

ffmpeg is not deprecated, so that answer is actually very misleading.

What should I do?

Comment: Is there something else misleading about that answer? Minor phrasing woes do not really warrant a vote reversal. If you want to clarify a misconception about the avconv/ffmpeg development, just add a comment.

Comment: Perhaps just refer to this answer, which seems to explain the source of the current "confusion"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756

Comment: "I really need to downvote" https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @BoltClock I only ever change things I have participated in, so that's not even remotely correct. If I upvoted something in the past, I try to revert that if it turned out to not be helpful. This way, someone isn't misguided by looking at things I have taken a part in, if I knew better.

Comment: Why did you upvote a misleading answer in the first place?

Comment: Just suggest an edit that removes `since ffmpeg is deprecated...` That turns it into a valid, non-misleading answer to the question. The user that posted that hasn't been logged in since July 2014, he's _not_ coming back to fix it.

Comment: You could, you know, edit it.  Done.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know -- I guess because I am human and thought that was correct at the time.

Comment: The question is off topic, so this really doesn't matter.